# How to check if one from two FK is null?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel)
    field_2 = models.ForeignKey(SecondModel)
```

And I want to display a form which both fields but only one field at the same time can be set, otherwise validation return error.

How to do it (preferably in the model)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel)
    field_2 = models.ForeignKey(SecondModel)

    def clean(self):
      num = filter(lambda e:e,[self.field_1, self.field_2])
      if len(num) != 1:
         raise ValidationError("only one attribute should be set")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me, I think this is a cleaner solution:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel)
    field_2 = models.ForeignKey(SecondModel)

    def clean(self):
      if not bool(field_1) ^ bool(field_2): # Using python exclusive-or (^)
         raise ValidationError("Only one attribute should be set")
```